# Difference between append and cons racket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to understand what the difference is between cons and append in terms of how the lists are being stored underneath. consider the case:

```
(define x '(hi, hello))
(define y '(randomvalue1, randomvalue2))
```

if I'm assuming that calling 
`(cons x y)` on these two lists will generate a dotted pair
where the first pointer points to `x` and the second points to `y`.

all in all neither x or y has been changed. Only thing added memory wise is the dotted pair.

However when I call append with the two lists:

```
(append x y)
```

I would assume that in order for racket to avoid changing `x` and `y` it will have to create a new list with for entries with copies of the values of `x` and `y` in order. This list does not have any pointers pointing to neither `x` or `y`.

Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to write lists, using `(list ...)` where `(list <a> <b> <c> <d>)` is a shorthand for `(cons <a> (cons <b> (cons <c> (cons <d> empty))))`

Before getting to your question, there is an issue I would like to mention:

```
(define x '(hi, hello))
(define y '(randomvalue1, randomvalue2))
```

will result in:

```
(list 'hi ',hello)
(list 'randomvalue1 ',randomvalue2)
```

Do you mean to write:

```
(define x '(hi hello))
(define y '(randomvalue1 randomvalue2))
```

which results in:

```
(list 'hi 'hello)
(list 'randomvalue1 'randomvalue2)
```

?

---

Now, for your question, here's an implementation of `append`:

```
(define (append x y)
  (cond
    [(empty? x) y]
    [(cons? x) (cons (first x) (append (rest x) y))]))
```

Intuitively, it destructs `x` to elements and rearrange elements to form a new list. However, `y` stays the same throughout the function. Thus, the memory address of `y` in the result of `(append x y)` still points to the same `y` as before. For `x`, it does not.

Comment: "destructs" seems like a bad choice of word, because it could mean that the original "x" is somehow modified. Maybe something like "it iterates over elements of x"