# Append two functions recursively with Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm using racket language, but i'm having some trouble getting some expected results for a recursive function. My goal is to input an integer n and output the element n times, as a list.

' exclude the ' and the text, #lang racket

```
; take n (integer) e (scheme) build new list    
; 2 `() -> () ()    
; 3 `a -> a a a    
; 4 `(a) -> (a) (a) (a) (a)

(define (list n e)    
   (if (= n 0) e    
      (append e(list (- n 1) e)) ))

; (list 0 '())   
; prints '()   
; (list 2 '())
; should print '() '()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem would appear to be that `append` isn't doing what you're expecting it to - it unwraps and discards top-level empty lists. (e.g. `(append '(1) '() '(2) '() '(3)) ;; => '(1 2 3)`).

So, swapping [`cons`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._cons%29%29) in for `append` will result in (what I believe to be) the expected output.

```
(define (my-list n empty-list)    
   (if (= n 0) 
      empty-list    
      (cons 
        empty-list 
        (my-list (- n 1) empty-list))))

(my-list 2 '()) ;; => '(() ())
```

You should also reconsider clobbering Racket's built-in [`list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%29%29) function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115348/difference-between-append-and-cons-racket) has a useful breakdown of what `append` is doing internally and why it's undesirable in this scenario.

Comment: i know this is a bit late but thank you for answering the question. your input helped me solve this problem. **append** did work as you mentioned.